# I can't load Seurat package in R

Tags: r

I tried loading Seurat package in RStudio and it gave me that error

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Seurat’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/wdata/msmuhammad/workbench/miniconda3/envs/test3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /wdata/msmuhammad/workbench/miniconda3/envs/test3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so)
```

Did anyone face such an error?

Comment: Two possibilities that I see. Fix the env-variable for Rcpp or reinstall Rcpp. The failure is in loading object code from the Rcpp package. Apparently the Seurat package expects to find it (but fails) deep inside a directory tree that starts in the `/wdata/` directory and also has `../miniconda3/..` in it. I'm not sure where the rest of your R libraries for your unstated version of R might be. It's possible that merely installing the Rcpp package might solve the issue, but I fear that you may have "crossed wires" in the installation of one or more of Rstudio or R or Miniconda.

Comment: @IRTFM I tried reinstalling the Rcpp package and gave me the same error.

Comment: First check this question and the comment from Dirk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65418163/cannot-properly-install-load-rcpp Then if needed, you need to post much more detail before anyone can help you ( `sessionInfo()`, .`libPaths()` code that was used, whether miniconda3 was installed , explanation of why such a weird R library location exists.